# EF Core Db First: 'Value was either too large or too small for an Int16' Error

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I am developing a web application using .NET 5. I am using Oracle 12 as the database and generating entities with `Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore` v.5.21.

I have a table `TableA` in the database, and it has a column of type `Number(5)`. This column is used to store numerical values, and some of these values are above 95000.

When creating the entity, EF Core interprets this column as `short`, and when I query the database using EF Core, I encounter an error

> Value was either too large or too small for an Int16

The `short` data type can only hold values up to 32767, and the values in the database range between 95000 and 96000. I can not change database column to `Number(6)` datatype.

A new `DbContext` class is recreated with each scaffolding, so I extended this class with the `OnModelCreatingPartial` method in a  different file. However, I still encounter the same error when accessing entity data.

My actual `DbContext` is `PortalDbContext` which is in `PortalDbContext.cs`. I also created a file `MyPortalDbContext.cs` in which I have:

```
public partial class PortalDbContext 
{
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Personnel>()
                    .Property(e => e.IdNum)
                    .HasColumnType("NUMBER(5)")
                    .HasConversion<int>();
    }
}
```

I also tried to use `ApplyConfiguration` as:

```
public partial class PortalDbContext 
{
    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PersonnelConfiguration());         
    }
}

public class PersonnelConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Personnel>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Personnel> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.IdNum)
               .HasColumnType("NUMBER(5)")
               .HasConversion<int>();
    }
}
```

These two did not work.

What I am expecting is getting `IdNum` database column as `int` or `decimal` in the entity, even if it is defined as `Number(5)` in the Oracle database.

Comment: How are you creating the `Personnel` entity? Is this database first?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Int16.MaxValue Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int16.maxvalue).  It is declared as `public const short MaxValue = 32767;`. You probably have mapped the column to a `short` property in your model (which you didn't show us). Another possibility is that you did map it to an `int`, which would probably require a larger column. `Int32` has a max value of [public const int MaxValue = 2147483647;](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.maxvalue) (10 digits).

Comment: @DavidG Yes it is scaffolding with db first.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes the problem is actually it is. EF Core maps Number(5) to int16 automatically but I need int32 to capture numbers bigger than 32767. My problem is how can I map it automatically to int32.

Comment: Can you customise the mapping as per this article? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300

Comment: @DavidG I was using .net framework previously and doing it like the way in the link you provided me with. However, now I am using .NET 5 and I am not sure if we can have app.config or web.config in .NET5 MVC project.

Comment: I had a bit of a Google and it seems there is no way to customise the scaffolding. So you need to manually edit the entities every time you do it.